# Param in button to change activity

Tags: android, button

My button sends a parameter to the function.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/tela1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Chinese Day"
    android:onClick="loadPage"
    android:tag="page1"
    />
```

My function should use this parameter to load the page1 activity.

```
public void loadPage(View view) {
    String page = (String) view.getTag();                
    setContentView(R.layout.page);
}
```

How to make this work?

Tks

Comment: Are you trying to load an activity of the name of this param? Could you please make your question clear?

Comment: Why do you want to get the activity name from tag? You can directly start the activity using intent from loadPage method. **Intent intent = new intent(context, page1.class);** **context.startActivity(intent);**

Comment: I have 6 buttons, i like to use only one function to set the activit using the param buttom to especify the activity.
(sory for my bad english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to specify in the button's tag the name of the layout, right?
Try the following:

```
String page = (String) view.getTag();  
int layoutId= getResources().getIdentifier(page, "layout", getPackageName());          
setContentView(layoutId);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Accept the answer to help others with similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Java reflection API**.

Each activity is an integer in `R.layout`. You only need to search for the attribute inside `R.layout` and then get its integer value to shove into `setContentView`.

```java
try {
    String tag = (String) btn.getTag(); // Button in variable "btn"

    Class<R.layout> cls = R.layout.class;
    Field field = cls.getDeclaredField(tag);

    Integer obj = (Integer) field.get(null); // You could do these two in one line
    int value = obj.intValue();

    Log.i("Test", "Actvity id code = " + obj.toString()); // Testing code
    setContentView(value);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
```